# Backbone.js - parsing through and displaying large xml feed

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

Im creating a Backbone collection from an xml feed. The xml feed returns 110 articles (it is external and no way to return less). I load into a Backbone collection like so:

```
        parse: function (data) {
            xml = data;

            $(xml).find('item').each(function (index) {
                title = $(this).find('title').text();
                description = $(this).find('description').text();
                author = $(this).find('author').text();
                pubDate = $(this).find('pubDate').text();
                img = $(description).find('img:first');
                if(img.length){
                    src = img.attr('src');
                }
                parsed.push({id:id, title: title, author:author, 
                            description:description, pubDate:pubDate, src:src});

            });

            return parsed;
        },
```

I then display the first 10 items with a "load more" button at the bottom of the list. When the user clicks "load more", I want to load the next 10 items from the backbone collection. In the view, I do this:

```
    loadMore: function(){
        var ul = $('#news-list');
        var id = ul.find('li:last-child').data("id");
        var li="";
         _.every(this.collection.toJSON(), function(item) {
                if(item.id>id){
                    li += '<li class="topcoat-list__item" data-id="'+item.id+'">';
                    li += '<a href="#news-item/<%= item.id %>">';
                    li += '<img height="30" width="30" src="'+item.src+'">';
                    li += '<p>'+item.title+'</p>';
                    li += '<p>'+item.pubDate+'</p>';
                    li += '<span class="chevron"></span>';
                    li += '</a>';
                    li += '</li>';
                }  

                if(item.id>(id+10)){
                    console.log('in loadMore if');
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
        });
        ul.append(li);
    }
```

So the each loop cycles through the first 10 items, skipping them as they are already loaded (and less than the id of the last li child), then creates the list element html on the next 10, then exits. This seems inefficient though. Is there any better way of doing this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: think about using an underscore template for the li elements, this would make it a lot easier without using concatenated strings to generate html code-blocks.

Second: if you consider the looping inefficient just start at the item you need (based on your code, untested, just skipping unwanted loops)

```
var ul = $('#news-list');
var id = ul.find('li:last-child').data("id");

for (var i=(0+id);i<=(9+id);i++){ 

  var item = this.collection.at(i).toJSON();
  var li="";
  li += '<li class="topcoat-list__item" data-id="'+item.id+'">';
  li += '<a href="#news-item/<%= item.id %>">';
  li += '<img height="30" width="30" src="'+item.src+'">';
  li += '<p>'+item.title+'</p>';
  li += '<p>'+item.pubDate+'</p>';
  li += '<span class="chevron"></span>';
  li += '</a>';
  li += '</li>';

  ul.append(li);
}
```

Using underscore:

```
var ul = $('#news-list');
var id = ul.find('li:last-child').data("id");

for (var i=(0+id);i<=(9+id);i++){ 
  var li= _.template( $('#li-template').html(), {"item":this.collection.at(i).toJSON() } );
  ul.append(li);
}
```

$('#li-template').html() would be like:

```
<li class="topcoat-list__item" data-id="<%= item.id%>">
<a href="#news-item/<%= item.id %>">
<img height="30" width="30" src="<%= item.src%>">
<p><%= item.title %></p>
<p><%= item.pubDate %></p>
<span class="chevron"></span>
</a>
</li>
```